# Magento 2: All Products Not Displaying In Admin

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter

I have more than 5K products. Suddenly don't know what happen now on Admin Side

In `Admin -> Products -> Catalog` now it's displaying only 1K products.

All Filters are also Reset. Visibility All Ok for Product.

When i Export from Admin .CSV file has 5K products. On Frontend also it's displaying 5K products.

Done with Indexing & Caching. Check Product Status as Well.

Don't know where is the issue?

**[UPDATE]**

I have delete all records & import it again. It's working fine now :)

Comment: 1K = 1000 products?

Comment: Yes @KhoaTruongDinh. You are right

Comment: Do you have any error in you logs (magento, web server) or in your browser (JS console errors)?

Comment: Hi @AlexGusev No JS Error & Nothing in Log Checked. While ago it's working fine don't know what happened. So it stops displaying all records

Comment: Make sure your re-index process executed successfully?

Comment: Yup it's already checked 3-4 times. No Issue on that side

Comment: How many records are found total in the grid? Label "??? records found" to the right of the "Actions" dropdown.

Comment: 1000 records found

Comment: You have any custom related to `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml`?

Comment: HI @KhoaTruongDinh Yes in frontend i have Price & Other Custom Filters as well. I have my own Attribute Set & 20 Attributes. It's dealing with that?

Comment: Check the size node: `<size>10000</size>` in your custom file?

Comment: Using Amasty Advanced Search Extension in that they have `app\code\Amasty\Xsearch\etc\search_request.xml` & `<size>10000</size>`

Comment: There is any config of this extension which is related to the size node? Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47568/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Answer (score 0):

Check SQL statement to get totals count. Change method `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::create` from

```
public function create(array $data = array())
{
    return $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName, $data);
}
```

to

```
public function create(array $data = [])
{
    $collection = $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName, $data);
    $sql = (string)$collection->getSelectCountSql();
    $logger = $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
    $logger->alert($sql);
    return $collection;
}
```

then refresh your product grid and find SQL statement in the log (`.../var/log/debug.log`).

Comment: It's Magento Default `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php` not able to find file & function @Alex

Comment: Oh, sorry! This is autogenerated file. Look it for in `.../var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/CollectionFactory.php`.

Comment: In `system.log` 1] SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` : `5K` records
2] SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5816a3c2c53281_43273028` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id
It' saying temp table is not available

Comment: 'tmp' table is from Full Text search indexation. Try to remove `$this->_totalRecords = $this->searchResult->getTotalCount();` code from `Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php` (https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5641/files) This is not a real fix but probably helps to you. I have no ideas more :(